# Android Camera Closes on startup

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I'm using the Android Emulator, with my settings as shown in the image.

[image: settings as shown in the image]. But I get the following stack trace when I attempt to open the camera app. This problem does not occur on MAC OS X El Capitan. I'm currently running Windows 8 64 bit.

> emulator: WARNING: _get_pixel_format_descriptor: Pixel format MJPG is
>   unknown
>   emulator: ERROR: convert_frame: Source pixel format MJPG is
>   unknown
>   emulator: ERROR: _camera_client_query_frame: Unable to obtain
>   video frame from the camera 'AndroidEmulatorVC0': No error

Comment: what about real device ??

Comment: Emulator`s problem, of course

Comment: I tried reinstalling the emulator again on my windows machine, but for some reason that didn't fix it. I tried restarting my computer as well, and checked that the webcam isn't being used for anything else